# Determine if cordova app is launched by the os in the background

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

We are using a couple of plugins in our cordova ios application that can launch the application in the background.  Specifically these two plugins: https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon and https://github.com/oursiberia/cordova-plugin-visit.  Unfortunately when the app gets launched like this in the background it seems that there is no way to tell that it is running in the background through cordova.  I'm registering for the pause, resume, active, and deviceready events and the only event that gets delivered in this situation is deviceready which is also the only notification that gets delivered in cordova if the app is launched by a user in the foreground.  In an ios native app I would be able to check the launchOptions in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to see if it launched with UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey or I could check [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] to determine if the app is running in the background.  Is there any way to determine whether the app is launched in the background in cordova or in any cordova plugin that anyone knows about?  I have been searching online for a while and haven't found anything.

Comment: Hi Alec, I'm having the exact same issue - did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own plugin to do this.  Here's what it does to determine if the app is running in the background on ios:

```
- (void)isAppRunningInForeground:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand *)command {
NSLog(@"- CDVAppState isAppRunningInForeground");
CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult
                           resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK
                           messageAsBool:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive];

[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
```

}